# Rolling one, two, three, or four 20-sided dice (d20)

Tags: probability, dice

In this situation there are 20-sided dice (or d20) with equal chances for all values. A "success" in each scenario would be a result of a certain value *or higher*.

For example, if a 13 is needed to succeed, it means that 13 and all greater values are a success, total of 40% chance to succeed. If a 3 is needed to succeed, 3 and all greater values would yield a success, for a total of 90% chance to succeed - *and so on*.

If we use the example of 13 to understand a situation in which we roll *two* d20s instead of one, a single success would be calculated as follow: each individual die has the same 40% chance to yield a success, which we can sum, but we'll have to subtract the chance to succeed *with both* (I imagine this like a Venn diagram, where the overlap is "added twice"). The total chance would be 2 times 0.4, minus 0.4 squared = 0.64, or 64%.

**What I'm struggling with** is the *three* and *four* d20s situations. How do I approach this? I get confused from all of the possible "double-overlaps", I can't reach a solid conclusion.

I tried using a binomial logic, but ended up with really weird chances, even negative ones!

Please help me understand, I'd really appreciate it if you'd add an example with your explanation. *Thanks a lot in advance :)*

Comment: Sometimes it's easier to calculate the probability that you fail.  In order to fail, every single die roll has to fail.  In your example, the probability that a single roll fails is $0.6$.  So, the probability three rolls fail is $0.6^3$, and the probability at least one succeeds is $1 - 0.6^3 = 0.784$.

Comment: If you're rolling $n$ die, the probability that *at least one* face is $13$ or larger equals $$1-(1-0.4)^n$$

Comment: With regards to what you were reaching for... [inclusion-exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) for three sets can be written as $|A\cup B\cup C|=|A|+|B|+|C|-|A\cap B|-|A\cap C|-|B\cap C|+|A\cap B\cap C|$, so you remove the overlaps of any pair, but in doing so you removed too much and so you need to put back in the triple overlap.  It continues for four or more sets as well, $|\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^n A_i| = \sum\limits_{\Delta \subseteq [n]}(-1)^{|\Delta|+1}|\bigcap\limits_{i\in \Delta}A_i|$

Comment: It would be handsome to describe the event of which you want to find the probability. I suspect the occurrence of at least one succes. If so then @MatthewPilling gives you a smart shortcut.

Comment: That is to say, you alternate between adding each individual, subtracting each pair, adding each triple, subtracting each quadruple, adding each quintuple, etc... either adding or subtracting each collection.  While I wrote the above with respect to $|~~|$, it works just as well for probability or other measures as well.